# WP7 Binding a local icon from a path

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-7

I'm using MVVM to bind my model data to a listbox on Windows Phone 7 but I cant figure out how to bind an icon to the list. 
I have an image in the template which is bound to the Icon property which is something like "/icons/icon-wo.png"

```
<Image Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Source="{Binding Icon}" Margin="0,0,12,0"/>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="29.333"/>
```

But the image doesnt show up, so I tried using a ValueConverter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));
}
```

How do I make this work pointing to local image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using a `Relative` Uri and you need to make sure that the "Build Action" on the image is set to `Content`.

**Update:**

This works for me in a new project:

```
<Image Height="100" Source="{Binding}" />
```

Then in the code behind:

```
this.DataContext = new Uri("/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Ok, I changed both of those and its still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: @d1k_is set the property to be a Uri and you shouldn't need the converter. See updated answer

Comment: Just tried:
return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative));
and it works so maybe it has something todo with the folder?